# output of ntpd --version

Tags: 12.04

In my ubuntu 12.04

```
#ntpd --version
ntpd 4.2.8p6@1.3265-o Wed Mar  2 06:23:51 UTC 2016 (5)
```

in the above "(5)" represents what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date after the version number stands for the time when the version was compiled.

<s>My guess is that the `(5)` has something to do with the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) value. Maybe the time difference to UTC, in this case +5 hours? So far I couldn't find a document for that.</s>

Seems like the number `(5)` stands for the times the makefile was executed (thx [@ Sharath Manchala](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741084/output-of-ntpd-version#comment1102316_741123)).

---

The version style is the following, just for proving my guess about the UTC date.

```
NTP uses A.B.C - style release numbers.

At the moment:

 A is 4, for ntp V4.
 B is the major release number.
 C is the minor release number.  Even numbers are 'stable' releases and
 odd numbers are "development" releases.

Following the release number may be the letter 'p' followed by a number.
This indicates a point (or patch) release.

Release candidates have -RC in the release number.

Here are some recent versions numbers as an example:

 4.2.2      A production release (from the ntp-stable repository)
 4.2.2p2    A production release (from the ntp-stable repository)
 4.2.3p12   A development release
 4.2.3p15-rc1   A release candidate for 4.2.4
```

Comment: Hi wittich, I am installing ntp latest package in my machine by running the "make install" command from the extacted package. The number is keep on incrementing when i do make install again and again.

Comment: Thx I corrected my answer.